# Git Init in home directory - now unable to commit changes

Tags: git, bash, github, version-control, git-bash

Git noob here, it's my first try with git on bash, and I did git init in my home directory. 
I realised that was wrong and then used rm -rf $HOME/.git to undo it.

Now when I try to commit changes in another directory called git-practice, it says branch master and won't commit any files I have added to the staging area.

When I try git add, the following comes up in the terminal:

On branch master

Initial commit

Untracked files: (use "git add ..." to include in what will be committed)

README.txt

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)

I am confused, how do I fix this?

Comment: You can't just switch directories with Git still knowing about the branches in the old location.  Your options include cloning again into the new folder location, or possibly moving your `.git` folder to the new location.

Comment: after using -rf $HOME/.git in my home directory I no longer have a .git folder  there. But I do have a .git folder in the directory git-practice. Was I wrong to remove the .git folder?

Comment: Removing that folder is totally fine. If you did not add anything to the git-practice folder so far, try to remove that .git directory as well and restart your trail with a fresh git init

Comment: You probably just need to do `git add .` rather than just `git add`. In other words, specify *what* you are trying to add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, please use `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` to check if the output is `git-practice` directory. If it is, that means you are working on this repo.

Then work with the git repo in `git-practice` folder. You can use `git add README.txt` or `git add .` to make the new file README.txt as staged. Finally use `git commit -m 'message'` to commit the changes.

Comment: Thanks Marina - I have found this and all these suggestions helpful